# Showing same template for all url of an Django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

Here are the two views :

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.views import View
  from django.http import HttpResponse

  class sectionOfficer_home(View):
       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return render(request, 'sectionofficer/UI/index.html', {})


   class sectionOfficer_main(View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return render(request, 'sectionofficer/UI/404.html', {})
```

Here is my urls.py of the app sectionOfficer:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (sectionOfficer_home, sectionOfficer_main)



app_name= 'sectionofficer'

urlpatterns = [
      path('', sectionOfficer_home.as_view(), name = "sectionofc"),
      path('secmain', sectionOfficer_main.as_view(), name = "secmain")
         ]
```

And here is the global urls.py:

```
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.urls import path, include

   urlpatterns = [
     
   path('sectionoffc', include('sectionofficer.urls')),
   path('secmain', include('sectionofficer.urls')),

        ]
```

But it showing always the first view template for any different url. What is wrong here ? Help please.

Comment: Both your urls in the app `sectionofficer` have the name `sectionofc`... Meaning if you use `{% url 'sectionofc' %}` or `reverse` or `reverse_lazy` they will always resolve to the first pattern. Give them a _different_ name...

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Do you type the urls manually, or do you follow a link from a page? If you follow links from a page show the code you write for them. (If you change a urls name, naturally you will have to change everywhere you refer that in your code)

Comment: I am typing the urls manually.

Comment: It is best to always end your url patterns with a trailing slash `/`, As directly you can see here `path('sectionoffc', include('sectionofficer.urls'))` with this instead of `sectionoffc/secmain` your url would become `sectionoffcsecmain` which honestly feels weird does it not? Plus your other patterns also don't appear to end in slashes, unless you have set `APPEND_SLASH = False` (would not recommend) you would be getting 404 for them.